# Is there a cost savings associated with 3 phase power at the same device power requirement (kW)?

Tags: power, three-phase, single-phase

I am a Mechanical Engineer looking into purchasing an annealing furnace and have seen that some operate on single phase power while some operate on 3 phase power. I've done some research and have seen that with 3 phase power, you maintain a more continuous flow of power and there is more power transmitted compared to the amount of conductor material used.

However if there are two separate furnaces that each require 15 kW of power to operate, and one runs on 1 phase power while the other runs on 3 phase power, is there any cost savings associated with selecting the 3 phase power furnace? Are there any other benefits to the 3 phase furnace that I am not seeing?

Comment: On the transmission level yes, but as a consumer it makes little difference. 15 kW sounds three-phase to me for practical reasons, but my vary from country to country.

Comment: @winny don't you have to apply a balanced load to the net after some point of power or otherwise you have to pay more? (e.g. a normal household not, but a company with some 100 kWs has to?)

Comment: @Arsenal you will at some point want to balance your load indeed because you don't want to pay for any reactive load consumption. No company wants to pay for energy that is basically useless. Since most devices are inductive, you will often balance it out with a capacitive load at the factory/plant entrance).

Comment: @Arsenal Varies from country to country and operator to operator. At 15 kW, you are just below the limit where I live. But I would still suggest three phase for simplicity.

Comment: Capacitors would take benefit from 3 phase, not sure if it has sense to use single phase on such large load, in my country the 7kW is max on single phase.

Comment: This will be very dependent on how the supplier charges for electricity in your area... You could be above an expensive threshhold or below on either singleor three phase. Find out the charges and bands and times...